# Probability of finding $N$ particle in volume $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, probability

a monoatomic ideal gas system of volume v' and number of particle N'.
a small volume present in it of volume v and number of particle N.
so what is the probability of finding N particle in volume v?

Comment: Is it binomial distribution,right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard combinatorics problem. Now, the small volume is v in a big volume v'. So, the probability of finding a single particle in the volume is $\frac{v}{v'}$.Now, simple choose n' particles out of n particles which you can do in $n\choose n'$ and multiply it with probability of finding n' particales and the remaining n'-n particles. The final answer will be - ${n\choose n'}\times{\frac{v}{v'}}^{n'}\times ({1-\frac{v}{v'}})^{n-n'}$